# Does LibreOffice Support AmiPro Format (.sam)?

Tags: file-format, libreoffice, compatibility

I was reading that LibreOffice was finally opening up in supporting many of the formats that were eventually been closed in OpenOffice every time an update appeared. I see that Lotus 1,2,3 and WordPro are there but does it support Amipro .sam format? I have about 10K documents just in one of the offices and work maybe more than 100K in total .sam documents and the only way to read them is using the AmiPro 3.1 original.

But I want to change them all to .odt format assuming LibreOffice supports amipro. If yes (via an extension or a new upgrade) I would search for a way via console to convert them from .sam to .odt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a couple of dollars, but the steps to get the SAM format to DOC or ODT is the following:

1. Buy/Download Lotus Word Pro - http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/products/smartsuite/features.html The reason is this will be the link between opening SAM files with no format problems and saving them in either Microsoft Word 2000 Format or Lotus WordPro format.
2. Open the newly converted file (Either DOC or LWP format) with LibreOffice.
3. Enjoy either saving it in the same format or using the ODT format.

This also helps because the Word Pro application includes converting of multiples files. I just did 16000+ files from SAM to LWP and then did a simple command in linux:

`libreoffice --convert-to odt *.wlp` - In case your files are WLP
`libreoffice --convert-to odt *.doc` - In case your files are DOC

I am sorry there is no other way. I have spent about 7 years looking for an option and, well, this is the only one right now. The only other way would be for IBM to release the source for opening SAM files and that would help in bringing many MANY medics, accountants, architects and others that have their research in SAM format to a new format. Just in my case I changed around 16000+ in medical documents from SAM to ODT and about 10000+ for other areas.

NOTE - I have checked as accepted until a better (Cost Free solution) comes out that works with no problems like the one I mention here.

Answer (score 3):

Well atleast for now it does not support it. But there is a way by which you can convert sam to doc and then maybe you can turn it into odt. Worth a try imho

http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm

Please make sure to read the whole instructions before merging.

Comment: Already tried that. Not exactly what am looking for.

Comment: After talking a couple of minutes with someone from the LibreOffice he said that this was not going to be implemented since it was something so OLD that it was sure to not be used. I agree also so i guess the only way will be doing each doc one by one.

Comment: Found an alternative to the one you mention. As it looks, it is much better when doing tables, macros and such. FileMerlin: http://www.file-convert.com/download.htm

Comment: The gmayor link mentions that the AmiPro converter is not working. They have then removed it from site.